# find and replace result of a list with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Is there a way to replace the value of one result with another after doing a linq statement?
is that in my linq statement in ** Status **, there are some that come to me with this result "PendingForApprover" but I want to replace it with "Pending for approver", I would like that after obtaining the result, you can use a find and based on that replace the values, before in my model I had it with a data annotation with a display name but for the reason that that result I am going to transform it into JSON and then it will be brought by server side that method is not working

y share my sentence LINQ

```
  var result = db.document.Select(d => new DocumentViewModel
  {
   DocumentId = d.DocumentId,
   Name = w.name
   ReceivedLogs = d.Logs
   Status = w.Status.toString(),
  .Where(l => l.Status == Status.Received)
  .Select(l => new LogViewModel
  {
     CurrentApprover = l.User,
     NameApprover = l.User.FullName
  }).FirstOrDefault()
  }).ToList();
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with `Switch expressions` it is a pretty clear solution and you can integrate it in your `LINQ` query.

```
Status = w.Status switch
{
    Status.StatusOne => "Status One",
    Status.PendingForApprover => "Pending for approver",
    _ => "Unknown"
}
```